# How to search data from table to other table - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my table structure:

**tbl_ward**

```
  ward_id   | ward_name
.....1..... | wardOne
.....2..... | wardTwo
.....3..... | wardThree
```

**tbl_room**

```
  room_id   | ward_id
.....1..... |... 2 
.....2..... |... 2 
.....3..... |... 1
```

as you can see `tbl_room` FK to `tbl_ward`. Now, I want to know if there is a code to search a data on other table.

I have 2 comboBox: 
`comboBox_wardname` & `comboBox_roomid`

If I select wardTwo in comboBox_wardname, I want to search all corresponding `room_id` on it and set it to comboBox_roomid.

*Example I select:*

```
comboBox_name
wardTwo
```

*Result:*

```
comboBox_roomid
1
2
```

I am using mysql 
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

MySQL code:

```
Select room_id from tbl_ward
JOIN tbl_room
ON tbl_ward.ward_id = tbl_room.ward_id
WHERE ward_name = 'wardtwo';
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a20b1/4)

OR

```
Select room_id from tbl_ward, tbl_room
WHERE  tbl_ward.ward_id = tbl_room.ward_id AND ward_name = 'wardtwo';
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a20b1/5)

Comment: it works. how bout i'm selecting different ward_name ? i am using jcombobox. thanks

Comment: Just insert another ward name in this part of the query `ward_name = 'wardtwo'`. If you change it into another ward there you get the rooms_ids from that ward.

Comment: got problem. when i add new room in wardTwo it appears multiple wardTwo in my comboBox and when i add again it appears 3 wardTwo. I mean when i click the comboBox i see 3 wardTwo items

Comment: @RimaTouya you have added data to the database? And now you have duplicates? If so alter the table and create a composited key (e.g. `ALTER TABLE tbl_room ADD PRIMARY KEY (room_id, ward_id);`). Only execute if you want the room_id and ward_id combined to be unique.

Comment: If you execute the code above you will not be able to add the same room_id and ward_id to the able tbl_room.

Comment: in tbl_room: room_id[PK] i already made room_id as PK and ward_id as FK

Comment: With this command you remove the primary key and create a new composite key. `ALTER TABLE tbl_room DROP PRIMARY KEY; ALTER TABLE tbl_room ADD PRIMARY KEY (room_id, ward_id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl_ward, tbl_room WHERE tbl_room.ward_id = value of the selected combobox
```

( won't work if you return ward_name since the value would be wardone wardtwo etc. )

Comment: @RimaTouya try my code or add this `AND ward_name = 'wardtwo'` to where clause of this sql query

Comment: @math487, what code should i put in "value of the selected combobox" ?